# Как досрочно прервать тренировку свёрточной нейронной сети. Pytorch

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, pytorch

У меня количество эпох равно 20. И вот после 15-ой эпохи происходит переобучение, я это выяснил экспериментально и поменял количество эпох на 15.
Как это в коде прописать, чтобы он автоматически завершал тренировку, если вдруг произошло переобучение
Вот код:

```
def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    log_interval = 1
    loss_func = CrossEntropyLoss()
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_func(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))


def valid(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    loss_func = CrossEntropyLoss()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            target = target.long()
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += loss_func(output, target)
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  # get the index of the max log-probability
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader)

    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
    valid(model, device, test_loader)
    scheduler.step()
```

Comment: Отслеживайте ошибку на валидационной выборке. Если она начинает стабильно расти, то останавливайте обучение.

Comment: Я отслеживаю, у меня растет до какого-то момента, доходит до пика и начинает снижаться.
Ну вот, к примеру(Accuracy считается на валидациноных данных):
```
1-я эпоха Average loss: 1.1062, Accuracy: 3464/4523 (77%)
2-я эпоха Average loss: 1.1062, Accuracy: 3464/4523 (84%)
3-я эпоха Average loss: 1.1062, Accuracy: 3464/4523 (86%)
4-я эпоха Average loss: 1.1062, Accuracy: 3464/4523 (80%)
5-я эпоха Average loss: 1.1062, Accuracy: 3464/4523 (75%)
```

Comment: Как видно на 4-й эпохе произошло переобучение, было 86% стало 80%.
Как в коде прописать, чтобы он автоматически прекращал обучение, увидев, что метрика падает

Comment: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/early_stopping.html